# Is it possible to perform a dissolve animation but control the progress, such as how you can with alpha?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to dissolve one UIImageView into another, but control the progress (so it occurs as the user pans their finger). This is simple with `alpha`, as I just change the UIView's alpha value as the user pans, but I don't know how to do it for a dissolve animation, which is slightly different from alpha changing.

Comment: What framework/api you are using for your dissolve animation?

Comment: take a screenshot of the view you have. also, how many `UIImageView` objects are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dissolve animation between two images can be made by placing one image on top of other and reducing `alpha` of the topmost image. This can be done in animation block. 
In case of changing dissolve according to user's pan gesture can be written method like:

```
- (void)setDissolveState:(CGFloat)state
{
    self.imageTop.alpha = 1.0 - state;

    // ensure bottom image is opaque, this can be done once
    self.imageBottom.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Here `imageTop` and `imageBottom` are UIImage's properties of the object (for example of the view controller) who processes pan events. When change in pan is discovered the method `setDissolveState:` should be called with relative position of the touch:

```
CGFloat relativePosition = (touchLocation.x - self.view.frame.origin.x) / self.view.frame.size.width;
[self setDissolveState:relativePosition];
```